# Best way to add these variables to an array or JSON to send?

Tags: jquery

These will eventually be going to a [Web Method] (asmx)

Here is the code:

```
$("#LessonContent").contents().find("span[class*='questionnumberincorrectsetting']").each(function() {
  alert($(this).html());
});
$("#LessonContent").contents().find("span[class*='questiontextincorrectsetting']").each(function() {
  alert($(this).html());
});
$("#LessonContent").contents().find("span[class*='textfeedbackincorrectsetting']").each(function() {
  alert($(this).html());
});
```

Okay, so there are three loops here all selecting different things, but they are all text so html() gets what I need.

EACH of these will return exactly the same amount of information. If the first loop goes 4 times, then the rest will pretty much be guarenteed to also loop 4 times. You get the idea.

The structure looks like this:

```
Question Number:

Question Text:

Question Feedback:
```

These three items make up one object that goes together.

Repeat for the amount of questions on the page.

What is the best way for me to store these? Would I be able to dynamically add them together based on an array and key? Is it better to try to use JSON objects?

Do I need a counter variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign each collection to variables. Then loop over one of the collections, and collect the corresponding indexes from all the collections.

```
var contents = $("#LessonContent").contents();
var qnumbers = contents.find("span[class*='questionnumberincorrectsetting']");
var qtext = contents.find("span[class*='questiontextincorrectsetting']");
var qfeedback = contents.find("span[class*='textfeedbackincorrectsetting']");
var questions = qnumbers.map((i, el) => ({
    number: el.innerHTML,
    text: qtext[i].innerHTML,
    feedback: qfeedback[i].innerHTML
})).get();
```

This will create an array of objects in the structure you want.

Comment: Thanks , that is nifty! I read somewhere the Web Methods can only take strings... Would I be able to pass this off to a web method? Most likely in an AJAX call.

Comment: You can convert it to JSON.

Comment: The feedback is undefined  after copy and pasting your code. The other two are good.

Comment: There was a typo in `innerHTML`.